# Authenticate Radius user using pam and ssh

Tags: ssh, radius, pam, freeradius

I am able to authenticate radius users using radius server+pam+ssh with creating local user with blank password in linux.

Is it possible to authenticate radius users without creating users in local machine with blank password?

/etc/pam.d/ssh file as below

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    sufficient      pam_radius_auth.so debug
auth    sufficient      pam_unix.so use_first_pass
auth    required        pam_auth_status.so                
account sufficient      pam_unix.so 
account required        pam_auth_status.so    
session required        pam_unix.so
```

Comment: Did you manage this. I am in similar requirement. I need to authenticate a user whose local account is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate the user without creating an entry for him in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files. But now , the user is not associated with any shell in '/etc/passwd' , so it can be of no use.

Do you want to launch a shell after authentication or you want the user just to be authenticated?

Comment: Can you elaborate the procedure for the same, Even my case I have the requirement that local account is not present, but the user is present in radius server, how can I authenticate this user... If I could divert it to some shell then it would be all the more better.

Answer (score 0):

I found two nss libraries that could help in this case:

- [libnss-mapuser](https://github.com/vyos/libnss-mapuser) from Cumulus Linux.
- [libnss-ato](https://github.com/donapieppo/libnss-ato)

The general process is that these will map unknown (but authenticated) user to a single user template. Each user will get his/her own `/home` folder though but both libs have in common that the user id will be the same.

These packages are mainly targeted at network devices where there is no ldap setup done. [Cumulus](https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/display/DOCS/RADIUS+AAA) describes the setup nicely.

I recommend reading https://serverfault.com/questions/538383/understand-pam-and-nss to understand what is happening there.